# Having trouble calling to a separate argument parsing function in main()

Tags: python, argparse

So, I'm trying to develop a script that will allow me to run a command as follows:

`python3 rhize_refactored.py -l <str>, -sa, -si <int>, -i <input_path>, -o <output_path>`

I designed my script such that the argument parsing steps are their own function, and then I call to them in main(). Here's what those sections look like:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def parse_all_args():
   parser= ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('-sa', '--automation', action='store_true', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-si', '--sample_id', type=int, required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_path', required=True)
   parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_path', required=True)
   args= parser.parse_args()
   return args.automation, args.sample_id, args.input_path, args.output_path

def parse_language():
   parser = ArgumentParser(prog= 'rhize_refactored.py')
   parser.add_argument('-l', dest='language', choices ['bash','python'], type=str, required=True) 
   args= parser.parse_args()
   return args.language

def r_bash():
   parse_all_args()
   if args.automation:
      stage_automation_templates()
   sample_id= args.sample_id
   s3_input_path= args.input_path
   s3_output_path= args.output_path`

def main():
   parse_language()   
   if args.language == "python":
      r_python() 
   if args.language == "bash":
      r_bash()
main()
```

When I try to run this script, I get several problems:

- It does not let me run the command in one step. I have to run `python3 rhize_refactored.py -l` first, and then it says I'm missing the `-sa, -si, etc...` arguments. But when I do all the arguments in one go, it says it doesn't recognize the arguments past `-l`.
- When I call to the argument parsing functions in main(), it does not recognize 'args', but even if I set `args=parse_all_args`, it has a problem with the if statements, such as `'str' object has no attribute 'automation'`.

What can I do to correct these mistakes and any others you foresee?

Comment: please, add the real code, the picture is not helping anybody

Comment: what is the point of an argument with `action="store_true"` that is also required?

Comment: when you do `return args.language` this is passing the value back to where you call `parse_language()` so if you don't do anything with the return value it is thrown away, functions don't share variables with each other.  if you want to set a global variable put `global args` in the function that sets it.

Comment: For the `-sa/--automation` argument, I didn't want it to require an argument after that. That's why I thought I needed "store_true" (as opposed to `nargs=0`)

Answer (score 0):

The commandline strings are put in `sys.argv`.  All `parse_args()`  commands read that list.  You have two parsers.  Both should be able to handle, or ignore, all possible strings you give it.

If `parse_language` used `args, extras = parser.parse_known_args()`, it would look for the `-l`, and ignore the rest.  You might also want to drop the `required`, and define a `default` (one of the 2 choices) instead.

`parse_all_args` will have to have handle or ignore the `-l` as well.  Again you could use `parse_known_args`.  Or you could include a `-l` argument and ignore the result.  Or you could pass the `extras` from `parse_language` to `parser.parse_args(argv=extras)`.

As pointed out in the comment, `required` with a `store_true` does not make sense.  If you omit `-sa` it will complain; if you include it `args.automation` will be `True`.  So there's no way of getting a False.

When you call `parse_language` you need to accept the returned value, and do something with it.  Same goes for the other function.

```
def main():
   language = parse_language()   
   if language == "python":
      r_python() 
   if language == "bash":
      r_bash()
```

I'd suggest changing

```
def parse_all_args():
   parser= ArgumentParser()
  ...
   args= parser.parse_args()
   return args
def r_bash():
   args = parse_all_args()
   if args.automation:
      stage_automation_templates()
   ....
```

These last changes are just basic Python function use ones.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure as to how you create a flag that doesn't take in an argument. For instance if I just want to run `-python rhize_refactored -b`, in which case `-b` doesn't take in an argument. What should the `parser.add_argument(.....)` line look like for that?

Comment: `store_true` doesn't take an argument; if absent the result if False,if present True.  It's a variation on `store_const`.